# Parquet format store bad records separately using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have been trying to load the parquet files but like to find if any bad records with in the parquet files and then store those records separately. This is quite possible for csv format (Pyspark has built in mode i.e. permissive) but I am not sure how this can be done for parquet. If anyone have come across this issue then please let me know.

Comment: Are you using Databricks?

Comment: I am using aws EMR, but does databricks has a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, but it's only available in Databricks: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/handling-bad-records.html#unable-to-find-input-file

Comment: Thanks, I have tried on delta lake and it did not work but I only used free version of delta lake so just wondering is it only for premium users? Is there any similar solution on pyspark or custom solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a delta lake feature, it sounds more like a Databricks feature. I don't know a similar solution for parquet format

Comment: Unlike .csv, there can be no "bad records" in parquet, because schema is stored in parquet and is validated for all rows during write. There can be "bad" files (non-parquet) in the directory you're trying to read, but thats a different matter.

Comment: Thanks mazaneicha, in theory I agree with you but I am able to do below scenario i.e
1) Write initial data with schema
2) Later some point I am able to append the data but one or more of the column type is different and no error while wring
3) Then tried to read and not able to read
so would be nice to catch bad schema/bad records while reading.